# BackupPC Per host file exclusion

Tags: linux, backup, backuppc

Is there a way to set exclusion directories per host in BackupPC?

I would like to skip /home on 2 of my web cluster nodes that use NFS Mounts to the master server.

Or, can I skip directories mounted via NFS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it in the web interface.

[image: Hosts Config]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, simple edit the files in /etc/Backuppc/pc/ for these two hosts. They are created in the schema {name}.pl.

There you can add the directive:

```
$Conf{BackupFilesExclude} = [
        '/home/*'
];
```